# Filter on Powerapps List

Tags: powerapps

I'm trying to filter a list that contains data like...

**MyList:**

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "item 1"
    description: "some description here"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "item 2"
    description: "some description here"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "item 3"
  }
]
```

...with the desire to show the "description" value on a dropdown component. So this works, but the item #3 for example does not contain any description key object there and the dropdown is only showing and empty space on its own list. How can I filter this in order to show only 2 items here?

What did I try...

```
> RemoveIf(MyList, description=false )));
> Filter(MyList, description=false )));
> Filter(MyList, Not IsBlank(First(MyList).description));
```

without any luck, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
Filter(MyList, Not IsBlank(description))
```

The expression in the second argument of the [Filter function](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-filter-lookup) will be executed for every row of the table given as the first argument.

Comment: Same result  here :(

Answer (score 3):

@RicardoGonzales, you must have an error in your code somewhere. Look closer. (there are two missing "," in the collection above)

@CarlosFigueira's solution is correct.

**Here it is in action:**
[image]

Comment: Thanks for this @SeaDude that was very helpfull